# A way of returning back to a position of code in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

How can i return to a position of code in ballerina after a condition check

for example

```
**Start:**

int value = io:readln("Enter 10: ");
if (value != 10)
{
   **goto Start**
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in ballerina so that the code keeps going back until the correct value is entered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code sample:

```
import ballerina/io;

function main(string... args) {
    while (true) {
        var value = <int>io:readln("Enter 10: ");
        match value {
            int i => {
                if (value != 10) {
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            error e => io:println("Input is not a number.");
        }
    }

    // Following code will be executed if and only if the input is 10
    io:println("Success! Input is number 10.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped alot